# Secured Nifi Cluster Setup

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to configure the 3node secured Nifi cluster setup by followinng the below [Link](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/11/29/apache-nifi-1-1-0-secured-cluster-setup/) .

But between nodes the connection not happened after enabled SSL/LDAP and i am getting the below error.

```
    2017-04-01 09:05:47,494 WARN [Clustering Tasks Thread-2] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Failed to send heartbeat due to: org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: Failed marshalling 'HEARTBEAT' protocol message due to: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2017-04-01 09:05:47,494 ERROR [Process Cluster Protocol Request-7] o.a.nifi.security.util.CertificateUtils The incoming request did not contain client certificates and thus the DN cannot be extracted. Check that the other endpoint is providing a complete client certificate chain
2017-04-01 09:05:47,494 WARN [Process Cluster Protocol Request-7] o.a.n.c.p.impl.SocketProtocolListener Failed processing protocol message from HKLPATHAS02.hk.example.com due to org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.ProtocolException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener.getRequestorDN(SocketProtocolListener.java:221) ~[nifi-framework-cluster-protocol-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener.dispatchRequest(SocketProtocolListener.java:133) ~[nifi-framework-cluster-protocol-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.io.socket.SocketListener$2$1.run(SocketListener.java:136) [nifi-socket-utils-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at org.apache.nifi.security.util.CertificateUtils.extractPeerDNFromClientSSLSocket(CertificateUtils.java:306) ~[nifi-security-utils-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.security.util.CertificateUtils.extractPeerDNFromSSLSocket(CertificateUtils.java:261) ~[nifi-security-utils-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener.getRequestorDN(SocketProtocolListener.java:219) ~[nifi-framework-cluster-protocol-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:431) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
        at org.apache.nifi.security.util.CertificateUtils.extractPeerDNFromClientSSLSocket(CertificateUtils.java:291) ~[nifi-security-utils-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
        ... 7 common frames omitted
```

Please guide me to resolve this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that one node in the cluster is attempting to make a heartbeat connection to the other node, but it is not providing a valid client certificate in order to authenticate itself during the TLS handshake negotiation. There are a few possible reasons for this error:

- The node is not sending the client certificate. Ensure that `nifi.security.needClientAuth=true` and `nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=true` are present in your nifi.properties file.
- The truststore on the receiving node does not contain the public key certificate of the connecting node. When you followed the instructions from that link, how did you generate the respective certificates? Using the [Apache NiFi TLS Toolkit](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#tls-generation-toolkit) as described by Pierre should ensure that all node certificates are signed by the same CA and that the CA is imported into the common truststore. If you manually generated your certificates, ensure that they are trusted on each node (you can do this with OpenSSL's `s_client` tool).